# Using SQL statement to add a query to table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to add a query result to a table in MS Access 2010 by running a SQL statement, but I get a time-run error saying

> Microsoft Access can not find the input table or query. make sure it exists and the name is spelled correctly.

This is my code, please help me to check where I am wrong.

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()

    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "INSERT INTO test(ConsumedDate, FinishedProudct, ConsumedItem, ConsumptionQuantity, Unit), SELECT ProductDate, ProductCode, [Ingredient/Packaging material],Consumption, FROM FormulaQuery"
   CurrentDb.Execute (strSql)

End Sub
```

Another question, can I use a datasheet form as input source in such condition?

Thanks

Jiangzhou

Answer (score 2):

```
...,Consumption, FROM FormulaQuery"
```

there is some comma in plus ;)